# control properties are changing on auto postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i am using the code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2me" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

After the AutoPostBack, i'm getting losing the class property of the dropdown control.Can you please help me to figure this out. hopefully, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting this class via code?

Comment: When you say class property, you mean css class?

Comment: yes, i mean cssclass